# How do I parse a log line in Java delimited by keywords?

Tags: java, regex, parsing, key-value

I'm working on a log parser that should parse a line like this:

```
ID1 : 0     ID2 : 214 TYPE : ERROR      DATE : 2012-01-11 14:08:07.432 CLASS : Maintenance    SUBCLASS : Operations
```

ID1, ID2, TYPE, DATE, CLASS, and SUBCLASS are all keywords and I want to have something like this:

```
ID1 : 0  
ID2 : 214  
TYPE : ERROR  
DATE : 2012-01-11 14:08:07.432  
CLASS : Maintenance  
SUBCLASS : Operations
```

I am really quite new to regex and I have the following:

```
(ID1|ID2|TYPE|DATE|CLASS|SUBCLASS)\\s*:\\s*(.+?)\\s*[(ID1|ID2|TYPE|DATE|CLASS|SUBCLASS)]
```

Of course, it does not work.

Any advice will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem in your expression are the square brackets, they create a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), this matches exactly one character from those inside.

```
(ID1|ID2|TYPE|DATE|CLASS|SUBCLASS)\\s*:\\s*(.+?)\\s*[(ID1|ID2|TYPE|DATE|CLASS|SUBCLASS)]
                                                    ^                                  ^
```

I made the alternation at the end also a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (The group starting with `?=`), so this is not matched, just ensured that one of those alternatives are ahead. I added also the end of the string `$` to the alternation.

```
(ID1|ID2|TYPE|DATE|CLASS|SUBCLASS)\\s*:\\s*(.+?)\\s*(?=ID1|ID2|TYPE|DATE|CLASS|SUBCLASS|$)
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?30ch8), a good tool to test regular expressions!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
        String s = "ID1 : 0     ID2 : 214 TYPE : ERROR      DATE : 2012-01-11 14:08:07.432 CLASS : Maintenance    SUBCLASS : Operations";  
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(ID1 :\\s+\\d+|ID2 :\\s+\\d+|TYPE :\\s+\\w+|DATE :\\s+\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}\\s\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\.\\d{3}|CLASS :\\s+\\w+|SUBCLASS :\\s+\\w+)");  
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s); 
        String res="";
        while(matcher.find()){
            res+=matcher.group(0)+System.getProperty("line.separator");
        }
        System.out.println(res);
```

I assume ID and ID2 are only digits and TYPE, CLASS, SUBCLASS are words.

**Output**

> ID1 : 0
>
> ID2 : 214
>
> TYPE : ERROR
>
> DATE : 2012-01-11 14:08:07.432
>
> CLASS : Maintenance
>
> SUBCLASS : Operations

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer("ID1 : 0     ID2 : 214 TYPE : ERROR      DATE : 2012-01-11 14:08:07.432 CLASS : Maintenance    SUBCLASS : Operations");
int i = s.indexOf("ID2");
s.insert(i, "\n");
i = s.indexOf("TYPE");
s.insert(i, "\n");
    //............The rest code for other keywords
```

NOTE: This is just a temporary solution what I know, there may be some more efficient logic.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use a regex like this: "(\w*)\s\:\s([\w\.\-\,]*)\s*"
and use a patern matcher this way:

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w*)\\s\\:\\s([\\w\\.\\-\\,]*)\\s*");
 Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s); 

 while(matcher.find()){
     //your couple "properties + : + value"
     System.out.println( matcher.group(0) );
     //your properties
     System.out.println( matcher.group(1) );
     //your value
     System.out.println( matcher.group(2) );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String format(String line) {
    return
    line.replaceFirst("ID2", "\nID2")
    .replaceFirst("ID1", "\nID1")
    .replaceFirst("TYPE", "\nTYPE")
    .replaceFirst("DATE", "\nDATE")
    .replaceFirst("CLASS", "\nCLASS")
    .replaceFirst("SUBCLASS", "\nSUBCLASS");
}
```